# Can I slow the speed of the cursor on a laptop touchpad?

Tags: thinkpad, trackpad

The cursor is too jerky and moves too fast when I use the Touchpad on my laptop in ubuntu 11.04 beta 2.

When I use Windows the cursor moves slowly and smoothly with precision. But on Ubuntu 11.04 Beta 2, the cursor is too fast and wobbly, imprecise.

When using the touchpad, is there a way I can slow the cursor down and make it more smooth and precise?

I'm using a Lenovo T410 laptop.

Comment: I meant to say TOUCHPAD above. Please replace trackpad with TOUCHPAD

Answer (score 1):

"sudo aptitude install synaptiks"

This is the touchpad configuration tool in Ubuntu and works very well for me when I want to tweak touchpad settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press the windows key, type in "mouse".  You can play with the pointer speed settings and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried this. changing the mouse settings had no effect on the touchpad

Comment: can you please run `xinput --list` and post the output.